# Problems with jCarousel

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I'm trying to modify jcarousel by displaying 5 items at once and moving 4 at a time, however, implementing the following code:

```
$('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    scroll: 4
});
```

still only moves 3 items at a time.

This works:

```
$('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    scroll: 1
});
```

by moving only 1 item, but once I go past 3, it doesn't move any more.

Any ideas?

Comment: how many images do you have in the carousel?

Comment: I actually figured it out. The `jcarousel-clip-horizontal` class' width was not set correctly. There were 5 items visible, each 90px wide, so the clip width needs to be 450px. Mine was set at 456px.